# Combining $parent and $index in a foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model that has two arrays. I want to iterate over one array and access the value at the same index on the other array, but it seems that you can't use `$parent` with `$index`. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/znnSc/):

```
function viewModel(factors,models) {
    this.name="parent View model";
    this.factors = ko.observableArray(factors);   
    this.models = ko.observableArray(models);
}

function subViewModel(name, array) {
    this.anotherArray = ko.observableArray(array);
    this.name = name;
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(
    ["factor1","factor2"],
    [ new subViewModel("model1", ["foo","bar"]), 
    new subViewModel("model2", ["one","two"])
]));

<div data-bind="text:name"></div><hr/>
<div data-bind="foreach:models">
    <div data-bind="text: $parent.factors()[$index]"></div>
    <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
    <hr/>
</div>
```

If you change `$parent.factors()[$index]` to `$parent.factors()[0]` it will display the right entry from the `factors` array. If you replace it with just `$index`, you get the right indexes. But if you combine them, it seems knockout isn't able to parse `$index` in an expression that already has `$parent`?

Anybody else seen this?

I know I could combine my arrays into a single array of a view model that combines the properties, but I have a reason for not doing that. This is part of a much more complex view model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$index` is an observable itself.

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

> This is the zero-based index of the current array entry being rendered
>   by a foreach binding. **Unlike the other binding context properties,
>   $index is an observable...**

So you need to write `$index()` if you are using it inside in an expression:

```
<div data-bind="text: $parent.factors()[$index()]"></div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv6eB/)